# Low WiFi range on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop on a partition, and when I am on Ubuntu, my WiFi range is significantly lower. As in, windows could detect my home wifi network from the basement with 4 bars, and on Ubuntu it doesn't even show up. Here is the output when I type in `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 70:77:81:2f:d8:9b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-67-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:38 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0c00000-f0c03fff
```

Here is the second part:

```
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 07
   serial: 30:8d:99:6c:9a:b7
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0b00000-f0b00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Is this an HP computer?

Comment: `rtl8723be` you say?? Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/752850/hp-stream-11-late-2015-edition-r050sa-wifi-not-working-properly

Comment: @old_boy_johnson I think I am stranger than chili555, I hope you upvoted his answer from the link