# RTL8723BE bluetooth signal drops after few centimeters

Tags: networking, sound, 17.10, bluetooth, rtl8723be

I have rtl8723be network adapter on hp laptop. OS is ubuntu 17.10 with kernel 4.13. Wifi is working and it can detect and connect bluetooth devices. However, bluetooth signal drops outside a few centimeter radius. The problem is similar to this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301243&p=13391183#post13391183.
`hcitool rssi` returns a value of -48 even when the bluetooth headset is close to the laptop. Blueman shows the received signal strength 35% (suboptimal), link quality 10%, transmit power level 50% (optimal). How can the signal strength be improved?

Comment: You may want to try [Changing the antenna select](https://askubuntu.com/a/752868/767056)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for a driver conflict with a generic driver for the same card. I had a similar problem with rtl8723bu (usb version of your pcie chip). I installed the driver from github but only had it working after blacklisting a driver called rtl8xxxu.

Comment: How can I check if there is a driver conflict?